# What is the most extensive PHP/MySQL combo book?

Tags: php, mysql

I know this isn't a directly programming related question but I need some help in deciding which book to buy. I usually never buy books, instead I download instructional videos and ebooks from file sharing sites. But I want to buy one big fat book now that I can read on the subways to and from work.

So for MASTERING php/mysql which book has helped you the most and you would recommend above all others.

Comment: Can't give you a name of a good book. But I can tell you how to spot a bad one.  

If in a given example you see $_GET or $_POST used as is, without proper filtering, that's a bad book. Why? because for the sake of simplicity or whatever it's ignoring the security of the application. And since you are trying o learn, the code you are exposed to should follow all possible good practices.
Just my 2 cents.

Comment: Well, then you have ruled out all beginner books ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how much experience you have with PHP/MYSQL, but the two main books that I have used to master PHP are Head First: PHP/MYSQL, which uses a really interesting graphical teaching method, and Advanced PHP Programming by George Schlossnagle.  Those are really the only two books you need to get up and running with PHP.  Read up on all of the content that is pre-built in PHP by using PHP.net.  Other than that, just code a lot.  The best way to master PHP is through experience.

Answer (score 0):

1. Head First PHP/Mysql --very good book that gets you on the right track.
2. PHP and MySQL Web Development 4th Edition --covers everything of php/mysql that a beginner needs to know. **EDIT:** This book is better off as a reference then a "learning" book because it covers a lot but not in depth.

AFTER you have learned all of procedural PHP, consider moving to a framework.

Comment: PHP and MySQL Web Development 4th Edition <-- This book is a mile wide and an inch deep. A zillion examples; very little explanation as to *why* things are going on. If you want to implement what the book is showing you, sure go ahead, but if you want to do something completely different, good luck.

Comment: @Billy- very true, it's a good reference book I should say. There's not a "really" good php/mysql book that's extensive. I learned php by reading those 2, then just looking at other's people code and say to myself "that's how they do that" and use it

Answer (score 0):

I've looked through a lot of books after just getting in and working on things for about a year.  None has been as useful as actually getting in, trying things out, and asking advice of people with more experience.

As such, I recommend Google and StackOverflow.